# How to clear items from Get-PnPTenantServicePrincipalPermissionRequests command?

Tags: permissions, pnp-powershell, spprincipal

I was learning how to use the service principal PowerShell PnP commands and everything was fine until I reached `Get-PnPTenantServicePrincipalPermissionRequests`. I understand how to grant and revoke permissions for this service principal and how to list the current ones but no idea of what is the mission for getting the requests made and how to treat them.

Is there any way of working with this collection of items? Because I didn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Get-PnPTenantServicePrincipalPermissionRequests` cmdlet returns a collection of `SPOWebAppServicePrincipalPermissionRequest` objects.  this object exposes both an `Approve` method and a `Deny` Method.  So, for example, if you wanted to Deny all permission requests, your code would look something like:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -url https://mytenant-admin.sharepoint.com -useweblogin

$permissionRequests = Get-PnPTenantServicePrincipalPermissionRequests
foreach ($req in $permissionRequests)
{
    $req.Deny()
}

Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Comment: @willian -Thanks for your response, it has complete sense!!! I'm trying to deny my requests but got an error. I made them with a wrong resource parameter and I think this is the reason why I'm failing. In the other hand, when I grant access to Graph, it is granted automatically without creating a request, do you know why is this happening?

Comment: I do not know why it would be automatic, perhaps there is another setting somewhere that makes certain types of requests auto-granted?

Comment: @willian - you have two commands in PnP to approve or deny those requests: ```Approve-PnPTenantServicePrincipalPermissionRequest``` and ```Deny-PnPTenantServicePrincipalPermissionRequest```. I figure out that they support in the SPOnline Cmdlets.